# How to populate a ListView with objects of a custom layout in a custom layout for ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using ListFragment which by default inflates a full screen ListView. I can successfully populate this ListView with objects of a custom layout.  My problem is, how do I populate these custom objects that have custom layout in a non-default layout in ListFragment?

This is the layout that I would like to inflate and place the objects in (id: "article_List").

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_footer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_footer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_footer_button"
        android:text="Next" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/article_List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_above="@id/footer_button_layout" >
</ListView>
```

Layout for my objects that populates the ListView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/journalTitle_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="journal title"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pubYear_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/journalTitle_textView"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="pubYear"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/volume_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pubYear_textView"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="volume"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/issue_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/volume_textView"
   android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="issue"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pageInfo_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/issue_textView"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="pageInfo"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/journalTitle_textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="artile title"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/authorString_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="authors"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

My custom ArrayAdapter class:

```
    private class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    public ArticleAdapter(ArrayList<Article> entries) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, entries);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // View of single article in ListView
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.articlelistfragment, null);
        }

        // This is the magic method that gets the article at position
        // "position"
        Article en = getItem(position);

        // if attribute value is null, then set textView visibility GONE.
        // Does not take up any layout space
        TextView journalTitleView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.journalTitle_textView);
        if (en.getJournalTitle() != null) {
            journalTitleView.setText(en.getJournalTitle());
        } else {
            journalTitleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView pubYearView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pubYear_textView);
        if (en.getPubYear() != null) {
            pubYearView.setText(en.getPubYear());
        } else {
            pubYearView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView volumeView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.volume_textView);
        if (en.getVolume() != null) {
            volumeView.setText("vol." + en.getVolume());
        } else {
            volumeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView issueView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.issue_textView);
        if (en.getIssue() != null) {
            issueView.setText("(" + en.getIssue() + ")");
        } else {
            issueView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView pageInfoView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pageInfo_textView);
        if (en.getPageInfo() != null) {
            pageInfoView.setText("pp." + en.getPageInfo());
        } else {
            pageInfoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.title_textView);
        titleView.setText(en.getTitle());

        TextView authorStringView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.authorString_textView);
        if (en.getAuthorString() != null) {
            authorStringView.setText(en.getAuthorString());
        } else {
            authorStringView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I would like to stick with ArrayAdapter. Using the default implementation of ListFragment to populate the ListView with my custom adapter I did the following (which worked):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Article> result) {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_bar);
        ArticleAdapter adapter = new ArticleAdapter(articles);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: u r almost there. in ur fragment, create an object instance of this adapter and set it to the listview

Comment: please could you elaborate...

Comment: ohk.. first of all, i would suggest u to use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter. do u know about BaseAdapter? BUT IF U WANT TO STICK WITH THIS, plz post the code of the fragment that contains listview, so i can elaborate what i meant

Comment: ok. please see above edit

Comment: add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged after setting adapter

Comment: but I haven't specified the id layout or anything for the new layout , so how would the adapter know  where to place the objects?

Comment: u have. see the getView method. getView method returns the layout for a single row (which in case is the layout with some 5-6 textviews).

Comment: i think you misunderstand. I am trying to place all the objects in the above layout. specifically in id:article_List.  I would like to use the layout right at the top as my returned view.

Comment: it dont have any textviews. where would u put those objects in that layout. if u return that view in convertview u cant access the textviews (u can but the process is very complicated). what u want is practically impossible (or i still misunderstood ur requirement).

Comment: ok. i got it!  My ListView should have contained the following android:Id= @android:id/list.